# How can I keep the intersection of a panel between dates using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, panel, intersection

I've got a panel of price data that has multiple IDs for each date.

```
Date          ID     price 
2012-06-08   1234     6.09
             2345     5.08
             3456     1.23
2012-06-09   1234     6.10
             3456     1.25
```

I need to keep only the rows where the IDs are the same for consecutive dates. I'm trying to calculate returns for a portfolio that changes every month and the only coherent way to do it is take the intersection of securities for consecutive dates and take the difference of the sum of those prices. I tried to filter the dataframe by iterating through the dates, but it wasn't fruitful. Here's my attempt ('hol' is my original dataframe and 'dates' is a list of unique dates in 'hol'):

```
newD = pd.Dataframe()
for i in range(1, len(dates)+1):
    newD.append(hol[hol['ID'][dates[i-1].isin(
        list(set(hol['ID'][dates[i-1]]).intersection(
            set(hol['ID'][dates[i]]))
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woody's answer got me nearly there, but I think the correct though perhaps inefficient solution is this:

```py
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'ID'])
df = df.unstack(-1)
df = df.diff()
df = df.stack()
df = df.reset_index()
```

The second line produces a column for each `ID` with one observation per date for every date in the DataFrame index; this is obviously inefficient if you have an unbalanced panel over a long time period. The third line then differences all these observations and produces `Nan` for all missing observations. The fourth and fifth lines returns the DataFrame in the original format. Note that `df.stack()` drops all `NaN` observations by default.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is exploit the `DataFrame.shift()` method in order to find the differences. If you combine this with groupby, when grouping on the IDs then you will end up results as I see that you want them. The trick is though, you need a DataFrame that has a date/ID pair of every unique date and every unique ID in order for this to work.

The process is as follows:

- Create DF with data you have
- Create a 'balanced panel' of data from that data frame that contains every date/ID combination possible from the DF you have. This will have price values where appropriate, and NA values where not.
- Group this new dataframe on ID, and use the `shift()` method to get the differences in the stock prices using the `apply` method
  +drop the NA row, which is akin to keeping only those observations that have consecutive days.

So I extended your data to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from numpy import nan as NA

D = [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 8).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 8).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 8).date(),
     datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 9).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 9).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 9).date(),
     datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 10).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 10).date(), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 10).date()] 
ID = [1234, 2345, 3456, 1234, 3456, 4567, 1234, 2345, 4567]
price = [6.09, 5.08, 1.23, 6.10, 1.25, 9.9, 6.0, 5.10, 10.0,]

DF = pd.DataFrame({'date' : D, 'ID' : ID, 'price' : price})
```

Then as follows:

```
#Now create a balanced panel of data based on the DF
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'date'  : [date for x in xrange(len(DF.ID.unique())) for date in DF.date.unique()],
                    'ID'    : [ID for x in xrange(len(DF.date.unique())) for ID in DF.ID.unique()]})

#set the index for both dataframes                  
DF = DF.set_index(['date', 'ID'])
DF2 = DF2.set_index(['date', 'ID'])

#Create a price column in DF2 that is NA where relevant observations are missing in the DF.
DF2['price'] = pd.Series([DF.loc[row, 'price'] if row in DF.index else NA for row in DF2.index], index = DF2.index)

#Sort the DF2 index
DF2 = DF2.sort_index()

#Group the data and apply a function that find the differences in price by shifting the data 1 place
DF2.groupby(level = 1, as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.price - x.price.shift()).dropna()
```

Gives me the following output:

```
   date        ID
0  2012-06-09  1234    0.01
   2012-06-10  1234   -0.10
2  2012-06-09  3456    0.02
3  2012-06-10  4567    0.10
```

Which seems to be what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. This doesn't work b/c 'date' and 'ID' aren't aligned. date is a block vector of the entire date range repeating every len(date.unique()) rows and ID is a block vector of the entire range of IDs repeating every len(ID.unique()) rows. The list comprehension for one or the other has to be modified. Unless I made a blunder. It looks like something funky happens either when the index for DF2 is set or when the dataframe is declared for DF2.

Comment: Right, so you would just need to `reset_index` on the dataframe you have right? In the DF I create date is in the columns, in yours its in the index. You need to get it out of the index to make it work using my system.... unless something else is going on?

Comment: My dates are a column as well. I'll get back to you in the morning. Something is fishy here.